# Finiteness for separated residually finite modules

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, modules

Suppose that $A$ is a commutative noetherian Jacobson ring and $M$ is an $A$-module.  Suppose in addition that $M$ is $\mathfrak{m}$-adically separated for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, and that $M/\mathfrak{m}M$ is $A/\mathfrak{m}$-finite for every $\mathfrak{m}$.  Does it follow that $M$ is $A$-finite?

If I imposed no separatedness conditions, then $\mathbf{Q}$ as a $\mathbf{Z}$-module would be a counterexample.  If I did not require $A$ to be Jacobson, or if I only imposed a separatedness condition at one maximal ideal, then $k[\![t]\!]$ as a $k[t]$- or $k[t]_{(t)}$-module would be a counterexample.

If it helps, I'm happy to assume that the $\mathfrak{m}$-adic completions $M_{\mathfrak{m}}^\wedge$ of $M$ are all finite projective of the same rank.  The rings I have in mind are polynomial rings over fields, or (strict) affinoid algebras over discretely valued fields, so I'm also happy to make additional assumptions (such as excellence) on $A$.

Comment: Just to clarify: even for a Noetherian, Jacobson ring $A$, most finite $A$-modules are *not* $\mathfrak{m}$-adically separated, e.g., $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is not $p$-adically separated except for $p=2$.  Krull proved that for every Noetherian ring $A$, for every finitely generated $A$-module $M$, and for every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$,  the localized module $M_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is $\mathfrak{p}$-adically separated.